# Conditioning the soup selection on a web scrape.Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code for an item of a list of products:

```html
    <div class="nice_product_item">
    <div class="npi_name">
       <h2>
           <a href="/solutii-mobile-telefoane-mobile/apple-telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-13-super-retina-xdr-oled-6.1-256gb-flash-camera-duala-12-12-mp-wi-fi-5g-ios-negru-3824456.html"> 
           <span style="color:red">Stoc limitat!</span>  
           Telefon Mobil Apple iPhone 13, Super Retina XDR OLED 6.1", 256GB Flash, Camera Duala 12 + 12 MP, Wi-Fi, 5G, iOS (Negru)
            </a>        
       </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="price_block_list">
        <span class="old_price">&nbsp;999,00 Lei&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="price_discount">-12%</span>
        <span class="cheaper_by">mai ieftin cu 120,00 lei</span>
        <span class="real_price">879,00 Lei</span>
        <span class="evo-credit">evoCREDIT</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some products got the price_discount span,while others dont

```
<span class="price_discount">-12%</span>
```

I use the following code to scrape the names of products:

```
texts = []

for a in soup.select("div.npi_name a[href]"):
    if a.span:
        text = a.span.next_sibling
    else:
        text = a.string
    texts.append(text.strip())
```

I don't know what conditions do I need to get the names of the products with discounts.

***Note:It has to work for a list***

Comment: What are you trying to scrape? Please [edit] your code to show the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to process the data could be to select all items with discounts:

```
soup.select('div.nice_product_item:has(.price_discount):has(a[href])')
```

Iterate over `ResultSet`, pick information you need and store it in a structured way like list of dicts to process it later e.g. `DataFrame` and save to csv, json, ...

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = '''
<div class="nice_product_item">
    <div class="npi_name">
       <h2>
           <a href="/solutii-mobile-telefoane-mobile/apple-telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-13-super-retina-xdr-oled-6.1-256gb-flash-camera-duala-12-12-mp-wi-fi-5g-ios-negru-3824456.html"> 
           <span style="color:red">Stoc limitat!</span>  
           Telefon Mobil Apple iPhone 13, Super Retina XDR OLED 6.1", 256GB Flash, Camera Duala 12 + 12 MP, Wi-Fi, 5G, iOS (Negru)
            </a>        
       </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="price_block_list">
        <span class="old_price">&nbsp;999,00 Lei&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="price_discount">-12%</span>
        <span class="cheaper_by">mai ieftin cu 120,00 lei</span>
        <span class="real_price">879,00 Lei</span>
        <span class="evo-credit">evoCREDIT</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []

for e in soup.select('div.nice_product_item:has(.price_discount):has(a[href])'):
    data.append({
        'url' : e.a['href'],
        'label' :s[-1] if (s := list(e.a.stripped_strings)) else None,
        'price' : s.text if (s := e.select_one('span.real_price')) else None,
        'discount' : s.text if (s := e.select_one('span.price_discount')) else None,
        'other' : 'edit for elements you need'
    })
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

| url | label | price | discount | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /solutii-mobile-telefoane-mobile/apple-telefon-mobil-apple-iphone-13-super-retina-xdr-oled-6.1-256gb-flash-camera-duala-12-12-mp-wi-fi-5g-ios-negru-3824456.html | Telefon Mobil Apple iPhone 13, Super Retina XDR OLED 6.1", 256GB Flash, Camera Duala 12 + 12 MP, Wi-Fi, 5G, iOS (Negru) | 879,00 Lei | -12% | edit for elements you need |

Comment: Thank you @HedgeHog,had an error for 'label' :list(e.a.stripped_strings)[-1],but i've used one of the construction above and it works

Comment: label2=s.text if (s:= e.select_one("div.npi_name a[href]")) else None
label.append(label)

Comment: 'label' :list(e.a.stripped_strings)[-1],
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @NFTChest: Thanks, in case that there is no `<a>` it is right to handle this issue. Improved my example by selecting the element more specific, so it should have `.price_discount` and `<a>`  -> | `soup.select('div.nice_product_item:has(.price_discount):has(a[href])')` | Your mentioned method with specific if-condition is working as well. Great.